# Como utilizar un archivo blob para un procedimiento?

Tags: .net, pdf, genexus, blob, genexus15

Estoy trabajando en Genexus 15, con el generador en .net.
Tengo una transaccion que contiene un estructura así:

```
ID
NOMBRE
CAMPO1
CAMPO2
BLOB (tipo pdf)
```

Quiero utilizar el campo blob, como input de una transacción, que toma un pdf le agrega una marca de agua y lo guarda en un directorio X.
Como hago para pasarle como imput ese campo blob?

Comment: Hola Matías, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. No está muy claro lo que pides ni tu problema particular. Explica mejor qué te sucede siguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Matías, cuando dices que "Quiero utilizar el campo blob, como input de una transacción", en realidad te refieres a que quieres que sea el _input_ de un `Procedure`. ¿Es así?

Comment: El programa que agrega la marca de agua, ¿cómo recibe el PDF? ¿Como una ruta a un archivo? ¿Como un binario? ¿Codificado en base 64?